# how to check if field is required in django model

Tags: django, django-models

I am importing a csv file.  I dont want to repeat code and rules that dictate which model fields are required in my model.

Is it possible to check if a field in a model is required?

Comment: -1 It's unclear exactly what you are asking. Do you want to check if the field is required in a ModelForm, like `some_form.some_field.field.required` or something completely different?

Comment: Its completely clear. I want to know if a field of a model (not a model form) is required.  @user777466 seems to have comprehended it.

Comment: Great glad someone helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get your model's field by :

```
f = YouModel._meta.get_field_by_name('yourField')[0]
```

Then ask:

```
f.null
```

Comment: the compiler says _meta is undefined. Is this the right syntax? Thanks!

Comment: yep, it worked on one of my projects. can you print your code and debug?